# List paths with find when the filename contains spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this code

```
for i in $(find pwd)
do
    echo $i
done
```

the problem is if the file name contains spaces, it prints on a separate line

how can I list all of the files in some directory including files that contains spaces

Comment: What is wrong with just `find pwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have the intended effect of your example:

```
find /path/to/somewhere
```

That is, no need to wrap a for loop around it.

But I'm guessing you want something more than just echoing. Perhaps call a script for each file? You can do that with:

```
find /path/to/somewhere -exec path/to/script.sh {} \;
```

where `{}` will be replaced for each filename found.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `while read` for this.

`find . | while read i; do echo $i; done;`

Edit:
Alternatively, you could just do `ls -a1`

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution

```
IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(pwd)
    do
        echo $i
    done
```

Comment: Why limited to `$7`? It will fail if the path contain more spaces, right?

Comment: The `awk` solution is a non-solution, as you are only processing the directory name, not the names of the files contained under the directory. While the `IFS`-based solution works, it only works for file names that don't contain new lines (which are rare, but legal).